# object deconstructing throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I'm passing a style object to a component

```
<Temp styles={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '1.6'}} ...otherprops />
```

When I try to deconstruct it, it gives me an error saying `Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined`.

The way I'm deconstructing it is as follows:

```
{({styles: {fontSize, fontWeight}}) => /* use the values */ }
```

The part that I don't get is that when I log styles, it displays the correct value, just when i try to deconstruct it it throws the error.

Comment: the left parenthesis between the braces was just a typo here right?

Comment: No, the code looks like this without the deconstructing. `{(props) => /* do something */ }`. I wrap the passed value.

Comment: In your example you have `{({styles: ... }} ) => `; the left `(` should be outside the `{`; should only be 1 `{` there too

Comment: the way i understood it was if I'm deconstructing, (props), then if i do ({styles}) i extract styles, if i do ({styles: {fontSize, fontWeight}}) i extract that from styles.

Comment: @vapurrmaid react passes everything down through props, so i have to first extract it from props and then process it

Comment: @vapurrmaid it is 2 levels deep: `props.styles.fontSize` and `props.styles.fontWeight`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following outputs `16 2` for me; the only issue I can see from the snippet you provided is the left parenthesis as I pointed out in comments:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Temp styles={{ fontSize: 16, fontHeight: 2 }} />;
  }
}

const Temp = ({ styles: { fontSize, fontWeight }}) => {
  console.log(fontSize, fontWeight);
  return <p>Hi</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```